# Base class members not being exposed in WCF service reference

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

In order to use a WCF SOAP service, I am using the "Add a service reference" tool in VS2015.

[image: Add a service reference]

The problem is when adding the service reference this way, the members of the base class are not exposed in the derived classes.

Here is my interface for my types:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(DbEntry))]
public interface ILogEntry
{
    [DataMember]
    Int64 Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    String Error { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    String CustomMessage { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    Int32 ApplicationId { get; set; }

    Int32 ServiceId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    Guid ApplicationGuid { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    String ApplicationName { get; set; }
...etc.
```

Here it the base class which implements the interface:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(DbEntry))]
public abstract class LogEntry : ILogEntry
{
    private Int64 _Id;
    [DataMember]
    public Int64 Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { _Id = value; }
    }

    private String _Error;
    [DataMember]
    public String Error
    {
        get { return _Error; }
        set { _Error = value; }
    }

    private String _CustomMessage;
    [DataMember]
    public String CustomMessage
    {
        get { return _CustomMessage; }
        set { _CustomMessage = value; }
    }

    private Int32 _ApplicationId;
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 ApplicationId
    {
        get { return _ApplicationId; }
        set { _ApplicationId = value; }
    }

    private Int32 _ServiceId;
    public Int32 ServiceId
    {
        get { return _ServiceId; }
        set { _ServiceId = value; }
    }

    private Guid _ApplicationGuid;
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ApplicationGuid
    {
        get { return _ApplicationGuid; }
        set { _ApplicationGuid = value; }
    }
...etc
```

Here is my derived class :

```
[DataContract]
public class DbEntry : LogEntry
{        
    private String _Message;
    [DataMember]
    public String Message
    {
        get { return _Message; }
        set { _Message = value; }
    }
}
```

In the client the only datamember that is being exposed in the DbEntry class is Message. When I use the CS file that is generated by accessing the WSDL directly then everything works great.

Can anyone tell me why the base class members aren't exposed in the DbEntry derived class when I use the "Add a service reference" tool?

Answer (score 0):

I commend you for attempting to program your code against interfaces, but I find that doing this out of WCF is not possible.  I still program against interfaces, but at the WCF level I include conversion code that takes the Interface instance and translates it into an equivalent WCF Model.

When you discover the service, it will only create objects based on what it can pass in or receive.  Your problem also deals with inheritance, as WCF won't extrapolate that for you, either.  You must reference both LogEntry and DbEntry as seperate objects that can be either passed in or returned by your Service functions.  In other words, you should have a seperate Operation Contract for LogEntry AND DbEntry.

Thanks,
Jibba

Answer (score 0):

Is it your WCF service? If so, place the models and interface for the service in a separate project, and reference that library from both your WCF service and your client application. I often name that something like `MyServiceName.Interface`.

(Even if it's not your WCF service but you're able to reference the models from your client app this still works.)

Then, when adding the service reference, click "Advanced" and ensure that "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" is checked.

Then, when you add the reference and the proxy class is created it will reuse your models as declared in your interface library. `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes won't matter. Because you're using the exact classes that you defined (not creating new proxy classes) your inherited properties will be accessible.